# Retain Values in new column when Appending a column to an existing dataset

Tags: data, machine-learning, column

I am working on a basketball data set. I am trying to append a "Class" column which looks at the "Pos" column and assigns a 1 if a forward (C, PF, SF) or a 2 if a guard (PG, SG). I am able to map a function that determines what the Class should be.

```
posassign[pos_] := 
 Which[pos === "C", 1, pos === "PF", 1,   pos === "SF", 1, 
  pos === "PG" , 2, pos === "SG" , 2]
ClassCol = posassign /@ bball4[;; , "Pos"]
bball5 = bball4[All, Append["Class" -> # & /@ ClassCol]]
```

The results look like this:
[image]

But when I try to append it only takes the "1" value:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing really to do with your question, but you could define your posassign function like this: `posassign["C" | "PF" | "SF"] = 1; posassign["PG" | "SG"] = 2`. A bit cleaner to read.

Answer (score 3):

For test data, I'm using the following:

```
bballData =
  Dataset[
    {
      <|"Pos" -> "C", "PTS" -> 100|>,
      <|"Pos" -> "PG", "PTS" -> 101|>,
      <|"Pos" -> "SF", "PTS" -> 102|>}]
```

Using your posassign function, you can generate a Dataset from bballData with this query:

```
bballData[All, <|"Pos" -> "Pos", "PTS" -> "PTS", "Class" -> posassign@*"Pos"|>]
```

This doesn't update the variable `bballData` itself (but if that's what you want just assign this new dataset to that variable). Hopefully you can see from this example how you could add/remove colums and apply other functions. I was inferring that you have a Dataset to work with, but if I've misunderstood which structure you want to apply your function to, then this would need to be ajusted.

Comment: (+1) You can also use `bballData[All, <|#, "Class" -> posassign @ #Pos|> &]`